# Ubuntu keyboard doesnt work when signing up

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu

I'm not a tech- person at all.. but im trying to get ubuntu on my mac.

Linux-Ubuntu sign up is where the problem starts. I need to choose a username, computername, password etc but my keyboard doesnt work. i can't type anything on it. nothing works.

help

Comment: When you say mac are you meaning iMac? If so are you using the bluetooth keyboard and mouse?  Ubuntu wont have them configured as bluetooth devices hence they wont work. If that's the case your best bet is to use a wired keyboard and mouse. If your using a macbook I'm not sure, do any error messages appear anywhere that may indicate an issue. If you do have a wired keyboard and mouse to hand see if they work as it could potentially be a driver issue but I'd be surprised with a macbook as I've found mine has always worked quite well with ubuntu installations.

Comment: Although my macbook is around 10-11 years old so may be somewhat different to yours if it's a newer model.